# unable to retrieve firebase key and delete object from firebase with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I am currently able to successfully push data to my firebase node (properties) and create a new property, but once I push the data I am unsure of how to find that key of the new property that was created to then delete it.

I am sure this is pretty simple but it still eludes me.

Thanks in advance. :)

code below:

```
angular.module('propApp')
.controller('propertyCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $mdDialog, $mdMedia, $mdSidenav){

    let database = firebase.database();
    let ref = database.ref();
    let uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    let propRef = ref.child('properties');

    // add new property function
    $scope.addNewProperty = function(){

        var newProp = propRef.push({
            street: $scope.property.street,
            postalCode: $scope.property.postalCode,
            apt: $scope.property.apt,
            city: $scope.property.city,
            state: $scope.property.state,
            landlord: uid,
            address: $scope.property.street + " " + $scope.property.city + " " + $scope.property.state + " " + $scope.property.postalCode + " " + $scope.property.apt
        })
    };

    // var newPropKey = newProp.push().key;


    // delete property function
    $scope.deleteProperty = function(){
        // delete property

        // new property variable
        var newPropKey = ????; //not sure if this is right

        // want to use a variable to delete property
        propRef.child('newPropKey').remove();



        console.log('deleted!');
    }

})
```

Comment: I don't know much about angular and how you can use this information but [firebase push](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push) returns a reference to newly created record. you can use `newProp` to do new actions with firebase.

Answer (score -1):

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('properties');

ref.push({some:'thing'}).then(function(snap) {
  console.log(snap.key);
  //look at the database to verify the key is there
  setTimeout(function() {
    snap.ref.set(null);
    //or 
    //ref.child(snap.key).set(null);
  },5000);
})
```

Comment: While your approach is right in getting the relevant key, I don't see why you need to use setTimeout to delete the data. According to the question, you just need to fetch the key, so that it could be used later for deletion.

Comment: The timeout is there just so he/she can watch the value appear/disappear from the database console as its pushed/removed, otherwise its not clear if the value was actually added to firebase since the poster wants it deleted immediately after its added.

Comment: From what I can gather from the question, the user does not want to delete the property immediately after its pushed. Instead, he/she needs the key to delete or operate in the required manner.

Comment: yes Utkarsh, you are correct. I am trying to delete the object later on once the user invokes the delete method not right after creation.